# Does a type of a parameter of a method contain the information of its class loader?

Tags: java

Two Classes with the same name but loaded by different class loaders will be considered different. Then a method uses such a type of parameter, can only the instance loaded by the class loader A be used by this method, but the instance loaded by the class loader B can't?

The following is my simple attempt

```java
// src/main/java/com/example/Main.java
// src/main/java/com/example/classloader/Foo.java

public class Main {
  public static void main(final String[] args)
      throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IOException,
          NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException {
    final String path = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource("").getPath();
    final CustomerClassLoader customerClassLoader = new CustomerClassLoader(path);

    final Class<?> customFooClass = customerClassLoader.loadClass("com.example.classloader.Foo");
    final Object foo1 = customFooClass.newInstance();

    try (final ByteArrayOutputStream memory = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
      try (final ObjectOutputStream de = new ObjectOutputStream(memory)) {
        de.writeObject(foo1);
      }
      try (final ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(memory.toByteArray())) {
        try (final ObjectInputStream se = new ObjectInputStream(in)) {
          final Foo foo2 = ((Foo) se.readObject());
          Main.class.getMethod("from", Foo.class).invoke(new Main(), foo2);

          final Class<?> customMainClass = customerClassLoader.loadClass("com.example.Main");
          customMainClass
              .getMethod("from", customFooClass)
              .invoke(customMainClass.newInstance(), foo1);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public void from(final Foo foo) {
    System.out.println(foo.getClass().getClassLoader());
  }
}


/**
package com.example.classloader;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CustomerClassLoader extends ClassLoader {

  private final String rootDirPath;

  public CustomerClassLoader(String rootDirPath) {
    this.rootDirPath = rootDirPath;
  }

  @Override
  public Class<?> loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    if (name.toLowerCase().contains("foo")) {
      return this.findClass(name);
    }
    return super.loadClass(name);
  }

  @Override
  protected Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    File javaFile = new File(rootDirPath + name.replace('.', File.separatorChar) + ".class");
    if (javaFile != null && javaFile.exists()) {
      System.out.println(javaFile);
      try {
        byte[] javaClassBytes = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(javaFile);
        return defineClass(name, javaClassBytes, 0, javaClassBytes.length);
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
    throw new ClassNotFoundException(javaFile.getPath());
  }
}
**/
```

there will be an error on `.getMethod("from", customFooClass)`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.example.Main.from(com.example.classloader.Foo)
```

What should I do to make `Main#from(Foo)` receive the Foo instance generated by `CustomerClassLoader`?

Thanks a lot.

---

Thanks to @user207421, after correcting `nameToLowerCase.contains("foo")` to `nameToLowerCase.contains("foo") || nameToLowerCase.contains("main")`,

```
          customMainClass
              .getMethod("from", customFooClass)
              .invoke(customMainClass.newInstance(), foo1);
```

works well.

So I guess that the parameter type's classloader must be the same as its class's class loader.

Comment: It will be good to have more context as it seems to be a design problem. You should avoid loading the same type in another class loader.

Comment: Instead of citing `Foo.class` literally, load the class from your classloader.

Comment: @user207421 `customFooClass` is loaded by my class loader in `getMethod("from", customFooClass)`

Comment: But you have `Foo.class` where you fetch the method at `Main.class.getMethod("from", Foo.class)`.

Comment: You may find [the documentation of ObjectInputStream.resolveClass](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#resolveClass(java.io.ObjectStreamClass)) informative.

Comment: @VGR How would that inform a question  that isn't about `ObjectInputStream`?

Comment: @user207421 It's about which class is loaded when deserializing from an ObjectInputStream, is it not?